# PHP Eclipse with Git - [git NO-HEAD ]

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm using PHP Eclipse Neon.2 with Git.

Up to now the projects in the Project Explorer were linked to the Git repositories (local). Files with not committed changes were marked in the Project Explorer.

But now all projects in the explorer show "[git NO-HEAD] instead of [... master]. The repositories, however, are correctly displayed in the Git Repositories view.

How do I restore the link between the projects and the repositories?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why. But simply renaming the projects in the Project Explorer solved the problem; i.e. restored the link between the projects and the repositories.